# Zip files according to quarterly year

Tags: command-line, scripting, zip

I have folders sorted according to the date from the past 5 years. I'm looking for ideas on a script or a way to zip all the files according to the quarter year to save my disk space.

For example, I have my mini-project folders saved in date format (Feb 14, 2022) from the past 5 years and I want to archive them quarterly year-wise.
from jan 2019 to may 2019 the folders should be compressed into a zip file and should be named as 2019 1st quarter.

Comment: Any alternative easy method is highly appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried so far, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Are you looking for file modification time to indicate the appropriate quarter, or is the year & quarter part of the filename? Please [edit] your post to indicate your current file situation and what you'd like the end result to look like.

Comment: Do these files change anymore? Or are they fixed, immutable? What does "according to quarter year" mean? Does it mean you want all files from the same quarter to end up in a separate zip file, or should there be one large zip file, but the order of files in that zip file is important? If these are supposed to be "one zip per quarter": Why? What's the advantage of that?

Comment: Hello Marcus, yes these files don't change, they are fixed and I want these folders to be segregated in a quarter wise for instance, I have folders from 2019 January to March, I need these folders to be archived as 1st quarter of 2019  and then from April to June as 2nd quarter and so on one zip per quarter. The main advantage is to save some space and safely archive the folders.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a representative sample of the directory structure and file names.   e.g. the output of `find top-directory-name/ -ls` redirected to a file and edited to remove all but the first few sub-directories and the first few filenames in each sub-dir.   Add the **text** of that edited output to your question (and format it as text in the SE editor, e.g. with the `{}` icon or with three backticks on a line before and line after the text), not a screenshot or other image. Don't add it in a comment, that would be unreadable.

Comment: Hey @PramodGeorge, but, having multiple ZIP files then isn't very useful – it just makes working with the files and archiving them more complicated. Wouldn't a folder for each quarter be simpler to use? You don't have to use zip to compress things – there's more useful ways to do that, which can then make use of the fact that maybe multiple quarters share similar data while compressing.